# Application capability v1.2 in hypereldger fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I have been trying to implement private collections in hyperledger fabric. I find that v1.1 has chaincode instantiate flag --collections-config however it seems to give an error on providing the file.If I update Application capability v1.2 it prevents peer from joining the channel with the error "Application capability v1.2 is required but not supported". Can somebody suggest a fix for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: tools]

Make sure the tools and command are the same version. I have met the error `Application capability v1.2 is required but not supported` when I run [first-network:release-1.2](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/release-1.2/first-network) with 1.1 tools. Because 1.1 tools don't support 1.2 capability.

Answer (score 1):

I just encountered this issue and the above solved my issue.
To provide a bit more detail on how I resolved my issue...

I checked out fabric-samples (as I'm attempting to spin up the hyperledger/fabric-samples/first-network example) so I can run the blockchain-explorer against the network and get a live view.

`bash fabric-samples/bin/cryptogen version`

I got:

```
cryptogen:
 Version: 1.4.1
 Commit SHA: 87074a7
 Go version: go1.11.5
 OS/Arch: darwin/amd64
```

Because my version is 1.4.1 I checked out branch `release-1.4` from the hyperledger/fabric-samples github repository.

Now I was able to spin up the network with:

```
./byfn.sh generate
./byfn.sh up
docker ps -a
```

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                                                                                  COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                      NAMES
c23d4764de06        dev-peer1.org2.example.com-mycc-1.0-26c2ef32838554aac4f7ad6f100aca865e87959c9a126e86d764c8d01f8346ab   "chaincode -peer.add…"   9 minutes ago       Up 9 minutes                                   dev-peer1.org2.example.com-mycc-1.0
409aa438f82e        dev-peer0.org1.example.com-mycc-1.0-384f11f484b9302df90b453200cfb25174305fce8f53f4e94d45ee3b6cab0ce9   "chaincode -peer.add…"   10 minutes ago      Up 10 minutes                                  dev-peer0.org1.example.com-mycc-1.0
6106a6b631e5        dev-peer0.org2.example.com-mycc-1.0-15b571b3ce849066b7ec74497da3b27e54e0df1345daff3951b94245ce09c42b   "chaincode -peer.add…"   10 minutes ago      Up 10 minutes                                  dev-peer0.org2.example.com-mycc-1.0
e2a68344d2a1        hyperledger/fabric-tools:latest                                                                        "/bin/bash"              10 minutes ago      Up 10 minutes                                  cli
acb5a0d9271a        hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest                                                                         "peer node start"        10 minutes ago      Up 10 minutes       0.0.0.0:8051->8051/tcp     peer1.org1.example.com
57215f1e79dd        hyperledger/fabric-orderer:latest                                                                      "orderer"                10 minutes ago      Up 10 minutes       0.0.0.0:7050->7050/tcp     orderer.example.com
176916aea8c1        hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest                                                                         "peer node start"        10 minutes ago      Up 10 minutes       0.0.0.0:9051->9051/tcp     peer0.org2.example.com
1c0a720149b8        hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest                                                                         "peer node start"        10 minutes ago      Up 10 minutes       0.0.0.0:10051->10051/tcp   peer1.org2.example.com
a9857d499c52        hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest                                                                         "peer node start"        10 minutes ago      Up 10 minutes       0.0.0.0:7051->7051/tcp     peer0.org1.example.com
```

I was attempting to run the hyperledger/fabric-samples first-network from the `master` branch and it failed to join `peer0.org1.example.com` to the channel available.

I attempted to restart the container with `docker start` this didn't work. I then attempted to start the container and attach to it to see what the logs mentioned.

```
docker start [containerId] --attach
```

```
[time] [peer] capabilitiesSupportedOrPanic -> PANI 01e [channel mychannel] incompatible: Application capability V2_0 is required but not supported
```

and this single container was shut down once again.

Using the correct release/version of fabric-samples with cryptogen appears to have resolved this issue my end.

More details on getting the blockchain explorer running alongside the network available on my post here: http://robevans.uk/?page_id=48